# How get "Section x.y" in header using \createmark with memoir?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

The code

```
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{\@secapp}{\ }
```

in the following source gives error that `\@secapp` is undefined.
I tried to use that by analogy with the use of `\@chapapp` in the preceding line, so as to produce, e.g.,

```
Section 1.1 Test section
```

in the odd-page header -- that is, include the word `Section` and *not* include a period after the 1.1 section number.

**Question:** How does one do that?

So far as I can see, the memoir docs don't speak to that.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\nouppercaseheads
\makepagestyle{mystyle} 
\makeheadrule {mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark}{}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage} 
\makeatletter
\addtopsmarks{mystyle}{}{ 
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ } 
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{\@secapp}{\ }
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MWE replace:

```
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{\@secapp}{\ }
```

by

```
\createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{Section }{\ }
```

You tried a `\@secapp` to imitate `\@chapapp`, but the `\@chapapp` is special in that its value will change whether or not an Appendix is being set or a normal Chapter; it is an internal LaTeX macro. There is no need for such convolutions for Sections.