# Write if statement to the toc

Tags: conditionals

Here is a challenge:

This construction works just fine as the if is contained to a single write statement

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi


\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA test\par \protect\testB}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

The code bwlow, on the other hand, will not work as `\testA` or `\testB` presumably gets executed inside the `\@writefile{toc}{...}` statement and we end up with and `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi


\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

So is there a good method for smuggling these two incomplete if statements into the toc file?

Comment: I thought I figured the problem out, but I just did part of it: The _first_ error comes up because the `\write` of `\addtocontents` is delayed until shipout, and at that time `\protect` has a different meaning. To remedy that you need `\protect\protect\protect\testA`. However, the `\@writefile` code uses some toks registers to handle end of lines, and then the unmatched conditionals are seen and chaos ensues. I'm not sure if this is doable without a heavy surgery in some LaTeX internals...

Comment: @campa then why do I keep getting an error on it?

Comment: Good question `:-)` Obviously also @PhelypeOleinik gets an error, so the problem (well, the absence thereof...) in on my side. My only clue is that on my work computer I have only TeXLive2017.

Comment: @campa Yes, this issue was introduced with LaTeX `2018/12/01`. More specifically, when fixing [this bug](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/73).

Comment: @campa check the aux, is the entry written there first or directly to the toc. I think is used to write it directly to the toc, nowadays it goes through the aux

Comment: Also in my case it's written through the `aux`. But never mind, I simply cannot test here. I'm sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\DeclareRobustCommand\activateif{%
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\deactivateif{%
\let\testA\relax
\let\testB\relax}



\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{
 \activateif
 \protect\testA test\par 
 \protect\testB
 \deactivateif}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

This lets the chapter entry in the toc disappear

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\DeclareRobustCommand\activateif{%
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\deactivateif{%
\let\testA\relax
\let\testB\relax} 

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\activateif}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA}
\chapter{test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\addtocontents{toc}{\deactivateif}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the usecase it has to use two separate addcontents lines, the main goal in the end is to be able to selectively show or not show a single contents line,

Comment: It shouldn't matter how many \addcontentsline you use: the main point is that `\testA` and `\testB` are harmless, when the toc is written at the end of the document.

Comment: Not understod, as far as I can see you cannot break your definition into three parts. Remember we have no control over the `test\par` part, that is just illustration. Try making the chapter contentsline not be printed in the toc by wrapping an if around it.

Comment: @daleif I added an edit which suppress the chapter in the toc.

Comment: Interesting, I was trying `\addtocontents{toc}{\activateif\protect\testA}}` ... `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}\deactivateif}` which failed. No, now they work, no idea what went wrong

Comment: hm, your braces are unbalanced so it is not quite clear what you did. And "end of the document" is probally nonsense, the commands should better be deactivated at the end of the *toc*.

Comment: That was a typo, hmm, will se if we can use this.

Comment: why do you need this? do you have text outside a \contentsline that must be suppressed?

Comment: trying to solve a question on the site where the user want two tocs each referring to the other but not it self. So a short toc would have a long toc entry in it and long toc a short toc entry. Since it is the same `.toc` in both cases, wrapping a conditional seems to correct way to go.

Comment: Do we even need the deactivate part? seems to run fine without it

Comment: hm, if there is a group around the toc probably not ;-)

Comment: Cool, to the trick is to sneak the definitions directly into the toc it self, then we are ok. Thanks,

Answer (score 13):

#### Edit:

This fix [was added](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/a128e23dc3966c77da49076d318f28e90adeb190) to the LaTeX 2ε and is available in the kernel since the 2020-02-02 release, so since TeXLive 2019.

---

The issue was introduced with the `2018/12/01` release of LaTeX. Before that, the macro `\@writefile` (which does the writing from the `.aux` to the `.toc` essentially did `\write\tocfile{\unexpanded{<stuff>}}`, so your unbalanced conditional was written without problems.

After the aforementioned release, a fix for [this problem](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/73) was introduced and the problem boils down to:

```latex
\let\testB\fi
\iftrue\else
  \toks0{\testB}
\fi
```

TeX doesn't care about balancing braces when looking for the matching `\else` or `\fi` of a conditional. In this case, `\testB` is seen as a `\fi` and you're left with just `}\fi`.

I think the definition of `\add@percent@to@temptokena` could be changed a bit to allow avoid this sort of problem:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi

\makeatletter
\long\def\add@percent@to@temptokena
    #1\protected@file@percent#2\add@percent@to@temptokena
    {\ifx!#2!\expandafter\dont@add@percent@to@temptokena\else
             \expandafter\do@add@percent@to@temptokena\fi{#1}}
\long\def\dont@add@percent@to@temptokena#1{%
  \@temptokena\expandafter{#1}}
\begingroup
\catcode`\%=12
\catcode`\^^A=9
\long\gdef\do@add@percent@to@temptokena#1{%
  \@temptokena\expandafter{#1%^^A
  }}
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, and probably cheating (at least in the case that this requires a recent latex, though not a bad requirement IMO)

Comment: @daleif Not really, this should probably be changed in the kernel for safety ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/202)). And the code above will work with prior releases, as they don't use `\add@percent@to@temptokena` (try adding `\RequirePackage[2018/11/01]{latexrelease}` before `\documentclass`). But as extra safety you can test for the existence of `\add@percent@to@temptokena`.

Comment: The fix proposed by you doesn't let users write comments to external files. Besides this the `\ifx!#2!`-comparison is still there which means that `#2` can still erroneously match up the `\ifx`, e.g., when doing things like `\@writefile{toc}{Some text\protected@file@percent My nice comment with \fi}`. In any case I'd prefer a routine which replaces each `\protected@file@percent`. (A minor challenge would be handling `\protected@file@percent` nested in curly braces...)

Comment: @UlrichDiez “write comments” is odd, but I assume you mean a catcode-12 `%` character. If that's correct, it's possible to do so, given the correct tricks to have the `.aux` see the `%` as catcode-12, not 14. It is possible, but I don't see why someone would need that, though. You are correct, of course: using `\protected@file@percent` in the argument would break things, but again I don't see why anyone would need that written to the `.toc`. It's just an “anchor” control sequence to be used by `\add@percent@to@temptokena`.

Comment: Not necessarily in the toc-file. But I've seen more than one person using `\newwrite\tf@extension`..`\addtocontents{extension}` for creating more or less arbitrary external text files `\jobname.extension` via the .aux-file, whereof some form, e.g., separate additional LaTeX documents...  (That's something that I would probably do by means of docstrip or the like. Nonetheless I've seen people doing this. In such scenarios you might like to keep things behind `\protected@file@percent` as comments...)

Comment: @UlrichDiez Seems reasonable to want to use `\addtocontents{extension}`, so it should probably work okay. If you think the `\protected@file@percent` thing is problematic, please do file an issue in the [LaTeX2e repo](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues) so that we can take a look at it and discuss what should be done. Ideas are very welcome!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that in more recent LaTeX2e-releases some `\add@percent@to@temptokena`-mechanism was added to `\@writefile`:

```
> \@writefile=\long macro:
#1#2->\@ifundefined {tf@#1}\relax {\add@percent@to@temptokena \@empty #2\protec
ted@file@percent \add@percent@to@temptokena \immediate \write \csname tf@#1\end
csname {\the \@temptokena }}.
l.19 \show\@writefile


> \add@percent@to@temptokena=\long macro:
#1\protected@file@percent #2\add@percent@to@temptokena ->\ifx !#2!\@temptokena 
\expandafter {#1}\else \@temptokena \expandafter {#1% }\fi .
l.20 \show\add@percent@to@temptokena
```

I assume this `\ifx !#2!...` is intended to be an empty-check for detecting whether `\@writefile`'s second argument contains the token `\protected@file@percent`. (If so, the first such token not nested in curly braces shall be replaced by `%` and everything behind it shall be dropped.)

1. I don't reccomend trying to write a percent-char trailed by an exclamation-mark as in:
   `\@writefile{toc}{something\protected@file@percent! This is a very important comment.}`
2. In case `\add@percent@to@temptokena`'s first argument contains unbalanced `\else`/`\fi` (as is the case with your scenario), these will erroneously match up the `\ifx` of
   `\ifx !#2!\@temptokena\expandafter{#1}`.

I foresee that this `\add@percent@to@temptokena`-thingie breaks a lot of home-brewed code written by users who rely on having the possibility of writing unmatched `\if..`, `\else` or `\fi` by means of `\@writefile`.

I might suggest something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\&=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 &
\@firstofone{&
  \endgroup
  &&-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  && Change \add@percent@to@temptokena:
  &&.............................................................................
  \long\def\add@percent@to@temptokena#1\protected@file@percent#2\add@percent@to@temptokena{&
    \ifcat A\detokenize{#2}A\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\@temptokena\expandafter{#1}}{\@temptokena\expandafter{#1% }}&
  }&
}%

\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like the e-TeX-`\detokenize`-thingie:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\begingroup    
\makeatletter
\catcode`\&=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 &
\@firstofone{&
  \endgroup
  &&-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  && Check whether argument is empty:
  &&.............................................................................
  && \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}
  &&                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  &&                       which is to be checked is empty>}
  &&                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  &&                       which is to be checked is not empty>}
  &&
  && The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
  && <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
  \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{&
    \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}&
    {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}&
  }&
  &&-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  && Change \add@percent@to@temptokena:
  &&.............................................................................
  \long\def\add@percent@to@temptokena#1\protected@file@percent#2\add@percent@to@temptokena{&
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}&
                        {\@temptokena\expandafter{#1}}&
                        {\@temptokena\expandafter{#1% }}&
  }&
}%

\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

By the way:

One could as well redefine `\@writefile` to only replace the first  `\protected@file@percent` by `%` while leaving everything else in place:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Change \@writefile to replace the first non-brace-nested
%% \@protected@file@percent in #2 by %
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\RemoveTo@protected@file@percent{%
  \long\def\RemoveTo@protected@file@percent#1\protected@file@percent{}%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 &
\@firstofone{&
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\Replace@protected@file@percent{&
    \long\def\Replace@protected@file@percent#1\protected@file@percent{&
      \@firstoftwo{ }#1%&
    }&
  }&
}%
\long\def\@writefile#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{tf@#1}\relax{%
    \immediate\write\csname tf@#1\endcsname{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\romannumeral0%
        \ifcat A\detokenize\expandafter{%
          \RemoveTo@protected@file@percent#2\protected@file@percent
        }A\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
        { }%
        {\Replace@protected@file@percent.}%
        #2%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA\protected@file@percent{This is my nice comment.}}
\makeatother
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Without `\detokenize` and without `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Change \@writefile to replace the first non-brace-nested
%% \@protected@file@percent in #2 by %
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\RemoveTo@protected@file@percent{%
  \long\def\RemoveTo@protected@file@percent#1\protected@file@percent{}%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 &
\@firstofone{&
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\Replace@protected@file@percent{&
    \long\def\Replace@protected@file@percent#1\protected@file@percent{&
      \@firstoftwo{}#1%&
    }&
  }&
}%
\long\def\@writefile#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{tf@#1}\relax{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\RemoveTo@protected@file@percent#2\protected@file@percent}%
    {%
      \@temptokena{#2}%
    }{%
      \@temptokena\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\Replace@protected@file@percent.#2}%
    }%
    \immediate\write\csname tf@#1\endcsname{\the\@temptokena}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\test{\noindent test\par}
\let\testA\iffalse
\let\testB\fi

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testA\protected@file@percent{This is my nice comment.}}
\makeatother
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\test}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\testB}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The !#2! is actually safe enough as \protected@file@percent is an internal kernel command that nobody should have occasion to use anywhere. (it is defined as \protected\def\protected@file@percent{} so it doesn't do anything useful as such) The case of the unbalanced conditional was an oversight, but otherwise the code obviously didn't "break a lot of home-brewed code written by user" given that is that way in the kernel for about a year now :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Most of the people using LaTeX I know don't use most recent releases but use older releases integrated in whatsoever Linux distributions. Therefore they are not yet affected by changes occurring in a kernel which is just a year old. Despite the statement in source2e that kernel macros can change at any time, which might break one's own work based on kernel macros, a number of people in my surrounding use kernel macros like `\@writefile`/`\@newl@bel` /`\@starttoc`/`\if@filesw` in their own ways in the endeavor of not having to reinvent the whole wheelwork.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach If I got it right, `\protected@file@percent` is intended to be used within the kernel as the last token of the second argument of `\addtocontents` in order to have it winding up in the second argument of the corresponding `\@writefile`-entry in the .aux-file for preventing the coming into being of a space-token at the end of the line in question when processing the external file (.toc/.lot/.lof/whatever) that came into being due to `\@starttoc{...}` and `\@writefile{...}{...}`.

Comment: There are clearly many people that don't use a recent version of LaTeX, but there are equally many who use miktex or TL and stay with recent versions and so far this issue was the first and only that showed. As to !#2!  the #2 has no payload it is either empty or \protected@file@percent unless somebody would start to use \protected@file@percent in random places.