# Junk with per-cent signs on pages at end of index

Tags: memoir, indexing, makeindex

For a book-length document, using the `memoir` documentclass, inputting many files, and using many packages, the pdf index has two pages of utter junk, consisting of per-cent signs and spaces, as shown in the screen shot below.

Given that the document is so complicated, I am unable to reproduce the behavior with a simple document so as to get a MWE.

The very last thing in my document source (in a subsidiary file) is:

```
\printindex\cleardoublepage%
%
\endinput
```

The end of my `.ind` is:

```
\item \idxmark{Zorn's Lemma}, \hyperpage{121}
    \subitem \gobbleone , \also{Hausdorff maximal principle}{121}
\item \idxmark{Zorn's lemma}, \mainref{114}, \hyperpage{114--117}

\end{theindex}
```

The definition of `\idxmark` from my preamble is:

```
\newcommand{\idxmark}[1]{{\let\gobbleone\relax\markboth{\sffamily\bfseries#1}{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}#1}
```

The unremarkable `.ist` file is:

```
% MakeIndex style file
% output main entry <entry> as: \item \idxmark{<entry>}, 
item_0  "\n\\item \\idxmark{"
delim_0 "}, "
% not forgetting the subitem case
item_x1 "} \n \\subitem "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Any idea of what the source of this very peculiar output might be? or at least how to proceed to find its cause?

[image: Junk at end of index]

Comment: You need to provide something for us to replicate. Otherwise, who knows.

Comment: The pattern looks kind of nice though, why not leave it in :D But for a real solution you will have to make an MWE. It may be a lot of work but otherwise it is near impossible to guess what is wrong. Copy your document and all extra files to another folder and start deleting content piece by piece until the problem disappears. Then put the problematic content back and delete all other content until you are left with a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Looks a bit like [this bug](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/202#issuecomment-552155354) which I reported yesterday. Does the problem go away if you add `\RequirePackage[2018/11/30]{latexrelease}` to the top of your document?

Comment: @Robert: I can't tell, since if I add `\RequirePackage[2018/11/30]{latexrelease}` then it causes havoc on compiling at all. E.g., it chokes on various pdf figures (with "Argument of `\@tempa has an extra }`" error), telling me that `\textprime` is already unavailable in T1 encoding; or telling me that various math command such as `\vec` are already defined. My document uses MathTime Pro 2, fonts but similar obstacles occur if I try to use `newtx` fonts or `cm` plus `amssymb` fonts.

Comment: @Robert: However, if I do *not* use that `\RequirePackage` but instead include the suggested code from the first method in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513685/13492, then the index error disappears! So it looks like it is that bug.

Comment: Then I would probably wait until tomorrow or so, when the update (patch level 3) should be available, and in the meantime, contemplate this abstract art work...