# Is this patch involving toc still needed in current LaTeX?

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals, bugs

A bug involving the toc and `\add@percent@to@temptokena` discussed in [Write if statement to the toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513617/write-if-statement-to-the-toc/513685#513685) can be fixed with the following code provided in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513685/13492:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\&=14 %
\catcode`\%=12 &
\@firstofone{&
  \endgroup
  &&-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  && Change \add@percent@to@temptokena:
  &&.............................................................................
  \long\def\add@percent@to@temptokena#1\protected@file@percent#2\add@percent@to@temptokena{&
    \ifcat A\detokenize{#2}A\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\@temptokena\expandafter{#1}}{\@temptokena\expandafter{#1% }}&
  }&
}%
```

Is this fix still required with the version of LaTeX included in TeXLive 2020?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's already implemented in the kernel.

The relevant [commit](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/a128e23), mentioned in my answer to the same post you linked, dates back to 2019-10-25, which means it got into the 2020-02-02 release, so it's present already in TeXLive 2019 (now frozen) and in TeXLive 2020 from the beginning.